# Should I be worried about files in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\` that Priviliaged Powershell can't delete?

Tags: windows

Going through my event viewer I stumbled upon two folders in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\`

1. Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.9.1.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrtf4b62535-506c-4978-ab73-b65ae9af9b03
2. SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_1.232.997.0_x64__zpdnekdrzrea08f17d678-b99e-4af7-9178-d6dd2f37975e

The event that triggered this find was `error 0x12C: Deleting file \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.9.1.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrtf4b62535-506c-4978-ab73-b65ae9af9b03\Clipchamp\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll failed.`

After some research I decided that it would be best if I just delete them. I opened an escalated powershell instance and tried, but got refused.

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.9.1.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrtf4b62535-506c-4978-ab73-b65ae9af9b03\Clipchamp.cli\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll: Access to
the path 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item Clipchamp.cli
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.9.1.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrtf4b62535-506c-4978-ab73-b65ae9af9b03\Clipchamp.cli\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll:
Access to the path 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item Clipchamp.cli
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.9.1.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrtf4b62535-506c-4978-ab73-b65ae9af9b03\Clipchamp.cli\System.Buffers.dll: Access to the path
'System.Buffers.dll' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item Clipchamp.cli
```

Should I be worried if not why am I having trouble deleting this folder?